# Batch file PATH overflow

Tags: batch-file, overflow

Sometimes I have a batch file like this:

`Action.bat`:

```
Set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Some\Folder\I\Need

foo.exe Bar1
foo.exe Bar2
foo.exe Bar3
@Rem Etc...
```

where `foo.exe` is a program that *expects `PATH` to contain a certain directory*.

Then I decide to use it for -- guess what? -- batch processing:

```
For /R %%f In (*) Do Call Action.bat "%%~f"
```

Now when I run this, `PATH` **easily overflows**.

What is the proper way to prevent this kind of overflow?

Comment: Rewrite `Action.bat` to not contain `Set PATH=...`?

Comment: @Adam: And what do I do about `foo.exe` not being able to find the files it needs?

Comment: move `SET PATH` to the invoking BAT, place it before the `FOR` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SETLOCAL`:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Some\Folder\You\Need

foo.exe Bar1
…
:: ENDLOCAL is implied at the end of the script, but you can add it explicitly
ENDLOCAL
```

All the changes to environment variables within the scope of `SETLOCAL` are, well, local. That is, they are discarded upon executing `ENDLOCAL`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ActiveState perl installed, you can use a perl one-liner. Add this to Action.bat:

```
set _dir=C:\Some\Folder\You\Need
perl -e "($x=$ARGV[0])=~tr/\\/\//;($p=';'.$ENV{q(PATH)}.';')=~tr/\\/\//;exit 1 if $p!~m[;$x/?;]i" %_dir%
if errorlevel 1 set path=%path%;%_dir%
```

The perl details:

```
# get directory to add from cmd line; replace \ with /
($x=$ARGV[0])=~tr/\\/\//;
# get path, surround with ";" to simplify matching, replace \ with /
($p=';'.$ENV{q(PATH)}.';')=~tr/\\/\//;
# return errorlevel 1 if directory not already in path
exit 1 if $p!~m[;$x/?;]i"
```

If you're doing this many times, it would of course be faster to have a wrapper batch file to do it just once.